# image not uploading in to database i have tried two methods but wont works

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing simple content management system while trying to upload a image nothing is happening . it simply refreshing the page . i have tried without image and its works properly while adding image in to that its not working

here my code

```
if(isset($_POST[submit]) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){                  

$information_id = mysql_prep($_GET['info']);
$menu = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['menu']));  // cut out whitespace for menu

$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

$img_des = mysql_prep($_POST['img_des']);
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];


$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$image = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$image = addslashes($image);
fclose($fp);
$content = mysql_prep($_POST['content']);
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}


$query = "INSERT INTO pages (
menu, position, visible, img_des, name, type, size, image, content, information_id
) VALUES (
'{$menu}', {$position}, {$visible}, '{$fileName}', '{$fileType}', {$fileSize},             
 {$image}, '{$img_des}', '{$content}', {$information_id}   )";
  if ($result = mysql_query($query, $connection))    {
  $message = "The new page was created successfully";
```

Comment: It is not a good practice.Store images to a folder and save address in database.Google search for fileupload in php

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Do you get any error messages? It's really hard to help you without more information on what's not working.

Comment: nothing is happening ... it just refreshing the page.. no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is with your query.  You should be escaping your input and using an sprintf statement.  Look here for an example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Also, mysql_query is deprecated.  Consider using mysqli

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to base64_encode your image first before saving it to the db. I use it and it works nicely.

Check out these links for more info:

[Save image to mysql db](http://www.mwasif.com/2007/4/save-image-in-mysql-with-php/)

[Save image to mysql db](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=store_images_mysql_php.php)

Try it and let me know if it helps you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload an image to a folder on the server and then save the path of the image into the database.

Comment: No you don't. You can save it as a BLOB in the database... it's only better to do it this way. Furthermore this doesn't actually answer the OPs question/